# Find the newest folder in a directory in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to have an automated script that enters into the most recently created folder.

I have some code below

```
import datetime, os, shutil 

today = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat() 
file_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime('/folders*')) 

if file_time < today: 
    changedirectory('/folders*')
```

I am not sure how to get this to check the latest timestamp from now. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is no actual trace of the "time created" in most OS / filesystems: what you get as `mtime` is the time a file or directory was **modified** (so for example creating a file in a directory updates the directory's mtime) -- and from `ctime`, when offered, the time of the latest inode change (so it would be updated by creating or removing a sub-directory).

Assuming you're fine with e.g. "last-modified" (and your use of "created" in the question was just an error), you can find (e.g.) all subdirectories of the current directory:

```
import os

all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
```

and get the one with the latest mtime (in Python 2.5 or better):

```
latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

If you need to operate elsewhere than the current directory, it's not very different, e.g.:

```
def all_subdirs_of(b='.'):
  result = []
  for d in os.listdir(b):
    bd = os.path.join(b, d)
    if os.path.isdir(bd): result.append(bd)
  return result
```

the `latest_subdir` assignment does not change given, as `all_subdirs`, any list of paths
(be they paths of directories or files, that `max` call gets the latest-modified one).

Comment: If the version of Python being used doesn't support the `key` argument (e.g. 2.4), you can use `latest_subdir = max((os.path.getmtime(f),f) for f in all_subdirs)[1]`

Answer (score 24):

One liner to find latest

```
# Find latest
import os, glob
max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

One liner to find n'th latest

```
# Find n'th latest
import os, glob
sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)[-n]
```

Answer (score 12):

And a quick one-liner:

```
directory = 'some/path/to/the/main/dir'
max([os.path.join(directory,d) for d in os.listdir(directory)], key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 9):

Python Version 3.4+

We can try [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and the solution will be one liner

**Find latest**

```
import pathlib, os
max(pathlib.Path(directory).glob('*/'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

**To get nth latest**

```
import pathlib, os
sorted(pathlib.Path(directory).glob('*/'), key=os.path.getmtime)[-n]
```

Comment: Nice one. Of course you will have to import `os` too

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to find latest directory

```
import os
import time
import operator
alist={}
now = time.time()
directory=os.path.join("/home","path")
os.chdir(directory)
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        timestamp = os.path.getmtime( file )
        # get timestamp and directory name and store to dictionary
        alist[os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file)]=timestamp

# sort the timestamp 
for i in sorted(alist.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    latest="%s" % ( i[0])
# latest=sorted(alist.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-1]
print "newest directory is ", latest
os.chdir(latest)
```

Comment: i am also looking for to create  a txt file with directory name and time stamp. and this txt file will get append after i run the above script every 30 mins. my intention is to create txt file with all the subdirectories name and path along wioth time stamp in one row.  how can i do that with the above code as timestamp variable gves some weired numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, datetime, operator

dir = "/"
folders = [(f,os.path.getmtime('%s/%s'%(dir,f))) for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(f)]
(newest_folder, mtime) = sorted(folders, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0]
```