# Python script to test for most recently modified file - inconsistent results

Tags: python, file, testing, directory

I found this post on stackoverflow which was exactly what I wanted to integrate into a larger script I am writing:  [Find the newest folder in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014554/find-the-newest-folder-in-a-directory-in-python)

I want to check for the newest file or folder so modified the script for testing as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1

import os

def allFilesIn(b='.'):
    result = []
    for d in os.listdir(b):
        bd = os.path.join(b, d)
    result.append(bd)
    return result

latest_subdir = max(allFilesIn('/tmp/testforlatest'), key=os.path.getmtime)

print(latest_subdir)
```

However I get results as follows:

```
> touch /tmp/testforlatest/file1
> ls -t -1 /tmp/testforlatest/ | head -1
file1
> /tmp/testfornewestfile.py 
/tmp/testforlatest/file1
> touch /tmp/testforlatest/file2
> ls -t -1 /tmp/testforlatest/ | head -1
file2
> /tmp/testfornewestfile.py 
/tmp/testforlatest/file1
> mkdir /tmp/testforlatest/folder1
> ls -t -1 /tmp/testforlatest/ | head -1
folder1/
> /tmp/testfornewestfile.py 
/tmp/testforlatest/folder1
> mkdir /tmp/testforlatest/folder2
> ls -t -1 /tmp/testforlatest/ | head -1
folder2/
> /tmp/testfornewestfile.py 
/tmp/testforlatest/folder1
> touch /tmp/testforlatest/file3
> ls -t -1 /tmp/testforlatest/ | head -1
file3
> /tmp/testfornewestfile.py 
/tmp/testforlatest/folder1
```

Would someone mind explaining why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong.

other information which may be of use:

```
> python3.1 --version
Python 3.1.3
> cat /etc/debian_version 
6.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `allFilesIn` only returns the last file returned by `os.listdir` because you append the results outside of the for loop. You probably meant this:

```
def allFilesIn(b='.'):
    result = []
    for d in os.listdir(b):
        bd = os.path.join(b, d)
        result.append(bd)
    return result
```

As an aside it's preferable to use lowercase and underscores for function names per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You could also condense the function into a list comprehension pretty easily:

```
def all_files_in(path='.'):
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

Comment: Thanks zeekay, that works - I'll know to check my indentation when things don't work in future.

Comment: Thanks also for the link to PEP8, appreciate it.