# python watchdog file mod notification

Tags: python, watchdog

The python code below is my first attempt for notification when a file is modified, however nothing happens when the file is changed.

What have I missed here?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print('file changed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/Users/jeff/smb/storage/wsjt-x/wsjtx_log.adi', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

NOTE:  I found that this code works well using Linux. It's on macOS Big Sur where I'm having issues.

Comment: Instead, did you get any errors when running ? For me it worked, I got to invocations of the print-handler when adding a line to my observed file while running.

Comment: No errors.  I run the script and in another shell make changes to the observed file, but the print statement is never called.

Comment: NOTE:  I found that this code works well using Linux. It's on macOS Big Sur where I'm having issues.

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17586617/15978922  awnser of your question ?

Comment: No, still no joy.

Comment: Which version of [tag:python-watchdog] are you using? See macOS-related  [bug #797](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/797) and resolving [feature #779](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/pull/779). Stumbling upon your path: when your file is in a mounted [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) share, then follow the [Watchdog Advice for CIFS](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/#about-using-watchdog-with-cifs).

Comment: I'm using 3.8.2.  however, the CIFS advice fixed my problem!  Write your comment as an answer and I'll check it off.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the linux mounts for the file I'm watching are NFS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying your environment in comments, one of following 3 approaches might resolve your issue.

#### Reproduction: Watching a local file on Linux

Running in one shell A and meanwhile using another shell B to add to the observed file `so.md` like:

```sh
echo "---" >> so.md
```

results in following output:

```sh
python3 so_watchdog.py so.md
file changed <FileModifiedEvent: event_type=modified, src_path='so.md', is_directory=False>
file changed <DirModifiedEvent: event_type=modified, src_path='', is_directory=True>
```

Here is the slightly modified version of your script (see comments):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print('file changed', event)  # added event to see the difference of two events for a single modification


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
       file = '/Users/jeff/smb/storage/wsjt-x/wsjtx_log.adi'
    else:
       file = sys.argv[1]
    # below only added the file as path
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=file, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

**Note:** This was tested on Linux, with a local file.

#### Watching shared files (CIFS/SMB)

Since your path `/Users/jeff/smb/storage/wsjt-x/wsjtx_log.adi` contains **`smb`** I assume, you are watching a file on a mounted shared network location using the [`SMB` (Server Message Blocks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol, also known as **`CIFS`** (Common Internet File System).

Then please follow the official documentation, [About using watchdog with CIFS](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/#about-using-watchdog-with-cifs):

> When you want to watch changes in **CIFS**, you need to explicitly tell watchdog to use `PollingObserver`, that is, instead of letting watchdog decide an appropriate observer like in the example above, do:
>
> `from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver as Observe`

So your import statement needs to be modified.

#### Watching files locally on MacOS

For MacOS the underlying file-system event API used is [`FSEvents`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) or FreeBSD's [`kqueue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue), instead of Linux's [`inotify`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Thus the behavior might also deviate.

Comment: Same null results with your edited script.  I run the script and in another shell make changes to the observed file, but the print statement is never called.

Comment: NOTE:  I found that this code works well using Linux. It's on macOS Big Sur where I'm having issues.