# Python - Copying Most Recent File From Folder with SubDirectories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to copy the most recent file from a series of folders. Here's the structure:

\\host\data\folder1\*.bk

\\host\data\folder2\*.bk

\\host\data\folder3\*.bk

\\host\data\folder4\*.bk

There are about 600 of these folders. I want to copy the most recent file from each folder to a single folder. Some folders could be empty as well.

I'm totally lost here and tried lots of things with no luck. This should be easy and I'm not sure why I'm having such a big issue.

Basic code,

```
import os, shutil, sys

source = r"\\server\data"
dest = r"e:\dest"

for pth in os.listdir(source):
    if "." not in pth:
        newsource = source + "\\" + pth + "\\"
```

Comment: As I'm at work, I'm limited in terms of what mock code I can put together, but I wrote something a bit similar not long ago. You're welcome to grab the code and play around: https://github.com/DavidMetcalfe/Archive-files-older-than-set-number-days

Comment: This is a nice script, but it won't work well for me. Sometimes there are files there from today, sometimes they are a week old, etc. So I only want to grab the newest file, no matter the date.

Comment: Since you'll be looking for the `mtime`, this might help for most recent, since I went for oldest in the provided script. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2014704/563231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the below in a text editor, so I wasn't able to fully test it; but this should get you most of the way there.

```
import os
import operator

source = r"\\server\data"
destination = r"e:\dest"

time_dict = {}

#Walk all of the sub directories of 'data'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    #put each file into a dictionary with thier creation time
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(subdir,file))
        time_dict.update({time,file})
    #sort the dict by time
    sorted_dict = sorted(time_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    #find the most recent
    most_recent_file = next(iter(sorted_dict))
    #move the most recent file to the destination directory following the source folder structure
    os.rename(source + '\\' + dir + '\\' + most_recent_file,str(destination) + '\\' + dir + '\\' + most_recent_file)
```

Comment: @HMan06 no problem, glad to help!