# Python: how to open last modified folder

Tags: python

I look for a code to open the newest folder with python 2.7.

After that I get x picures:

```
PATH = "/path/to/your/folder"
DST = "/destination/folder"

pictures = [os.path.join(PATH, pic) for pic in os.listdir(PATH)]
pictures.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
return (pictures[-7:])
```

what I can copy:

```
def kopieren():         
    for pic in get_last_pics():
        print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(pic)))
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(pic), os.path.join(DST)) 

kopieren()
```

Can anybody give me idea, how I can jump into the newest folder to get pictures insite from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the newest folder in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014554/find-the-newest-folder-in-a-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The following program allows you to get the last modified folder's path:

```
import os, sys

def get_newest_folder(path):
    newest = None
    date = None

    for f in get_all_folders(path):
        if (date == None or date < os.path.getmtime(f)):
            newest = f
            date = os.path.getmtime(f)

    return os.path.join(path, newest)

def get_all_folders(path):
    return [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(x) == False]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_newest_folder(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer. When I try to execude the code I get a       failure: `code`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(get_newest_folder(sys.argv[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range`code`

Comment: How can I specified the path? Like PATH = "/somewhere/"

Comment: The script is meant to be used as a single program, i.e. use it with `python nameofthefile.py /path/to/folder`. If you want to use this code in yours, you can just copy/paste `get_newest_folder`/`get_all_folders` and call the first function wherever you need it.

Comment: OK, now I understand. But I have still the same: `code:` sudo python test.py /var/www/html/Kamerabilder_Klingel_NAS     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(get_newest_folder(sys.argv[1]))
  File "test.py", line 7, in get_newest_folder
    for f in get_all_folders(path):
  File "test.py", line 15, in get_all_folders
    return [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(x) == False]
OSError: [Errno 116] Stale file handle: '/var/www/html/Kamerabilder_Klingel_NAS'

Comment: Can you upload "test.py" somewhere? Like, paste it in pastebin or hastebin? This would be very helpful.

Comment: From what I'm reading online, this error can happen when you try to read (in this case : `os.path.isfile(x)`) a file (or folder) that's been deleted.

Comment: My test.py is your code :-) As first I try to run it stand along. Then I can think about implement...

Comment: Oh, well. Like I said in my other comment, the program is most likely trying to open a file that's been deleted. It might also come from the fact that you're running the program as `sudo`. You shouldn't have to.

Comment: The folder isn't empty and it's doens't matter, if I use sudo or not. I always get the message: `code`<br/> python scripts/test.py /var/www/html/Kamerabilder_Klingel_NAS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(get_newest_folder(sys.argv[1]))
  File "scripts/test.py", line 7, in get_newest_folder
    for f in get_all_folders(path):
  File "scripts/test.py", line 15, in get_all_folders
    return [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(x) == False]
OSError: [Errno 116] Stale file handle: '/var/www/html/Kamerabilder_Klingel_NAS'

Comment: My best guess would be for you to check if the file exist before trying to open it (so, as I said in my other comment, before `os.path.isfile(x)`. I'm 100% sure this will fix the issue, good luck! Consider accepting the answer since it provides the solution to your original post.

Comment: But I want to find out, which folder (not file) is the newest. Do you mean, it would be work with your code? Unter Kamerabilder_Klingel_NAS I get automatically many folder, comming from camera. And I have to open the newest folder

Comment: My code only works for folder, it's the purpose of the program I wrote for you : to find the newest folder. If you have another issue, I suggest you to accept the answer and post a new question. Comments aren't the right place to discuss issues not related to the original question.

Comment: I still work on the issue, to jump into the newest folder - I don't have another issue. I always get the massage: index out of range on the last row of your code...

Comment: Index out of range? This isn't the error code you showed me in your other comments, these were OSErrors.

Comment: Oh, your very first comment? I already answered that. Please try to understand my comments, there is no issue with this code and you should mark the answer as accepted. Unless you provide me complete source code of what's causing the issue (and you're better off opening a new question for this), I can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, how to find newest folder:

[Find the newest folder in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014554/find-the-newest-folder-in-a-directory-in-python)

... a

It works !!!