# How to read the file name in a directory and print as output using timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a particular folder(Test) in my D drive. Every week a new folder gets created inside test like 1234,4231,etc. I want to write a python script which can print the folder name recently created. I was able to do upto this.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("D:\Test1"):
if file.endswith(".txt"):
    #print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
    s = os.path.join("/mydir", file)
```

Comment: so... you forgot to ask a precise question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the newest folder in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014554/find-the-newest-folder-in-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: How does it relates to `selenium-webdriver` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the names of all directories/folders along with their creation date from recent to old:

```
import os, time
DIR = "D:\Test1"
t = {}
for dirName in os.listdir(DIR):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(DIR, dirName)):
        t[str( time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(DIR, dirName)))))] = dirName

for key in sorted(t.keys(), reverse=True):
    print("%s : %s" % (key, t[key]))
```

**Here**

```
os.listdir(DIR)
```

gives the name of all the files and directories present in DIR directory.

```
os.path.isdir(SOME_VAR)
```

checks whether SOME_VAR is a directory or not.

```
os.path.join(DIR, dirName)
```

used to get the absolute path of the directory whose name is stored in dirName like if dirName is 123 the absolute path is `D:\Test1\1234`

Output :

```
2017-12-29 12:41:16 : Python
2017-10-30 11:30:55 : gccPrgms
2017-09-27 15:25:39 : Projects
2017-09-06 11:26:23 : shellscript
2017-06-22 08:59:19 : shashank
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want the output to be like '1234' and not as 'D:\Test1\1234'

Comment: That is how you will get the result '1234'.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. This gives you latest folder name

```
import os
directory = 'D:\Test1'
s=max([os.path.join(directory,d) for d in os.listdir(directory)], key=os.path.getmtime)
split_str=s.rsplit('\\',1)
final_string=split_str[1]
print final_string
```

Comment: Thanks but how to print the newly created folder name

Comment: This will give you recently created folder name

Comment: Have updated the script which gives you the latest folder name instead of the path.